# How does LUA block on a Redis Cluster?

Tags: redis

I understand LUA calls are blocking on Redis but I'm unclear on how they are blocked.

I have a Redis cluster with 3 nodes (R1, R2, R3) containing 6 keys (A, B, C, D, E, F) which are distributed evenly across nodes. My client C1 executes a LUA script on R1 targeting key A. Lets say this LUA script runs for 1 minute. During that time, C2 wants to fetch a key from, or run a LUA script against, key E in R3. Is C2 blocked until C2 finishes?

[image]

What if they are targeting different keys on the same node?

[image]

When a LUA script is executed on a redis cluster, *what* exactly is blocked?

Answer (score 2):

The node is blocked any time a command is executing, whether it is a Lua script, a simple `GET`, or anything else. This behavior is the same with a single-instance deployment and clustered deployment because the cluster is made up of multiple "single-instance"-like shards.

Comment: Thank you. So in the first example, C2 would not be blocked because it accesses a node that is not blocked by C1

Comment: That is correct.